# Answered question "put-on-hold" due to lack of "shortest code"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, answered-questions

This question was recently placed on-hold:

[Selecting features within certain buffer distance of selected feature using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/selecting-features-within-certain-buffer-distance-of-selected-feature-using-pyqg)

The reason being:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "Questions seeking help to debug/write/improve code must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Providing a **clear problem statement** and evidence of a code attempt will help others to help you. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

A fair enough reason, the OP asked for an answer which included code but didn't provide code him/herself.

But two answers were given, one of which was accepted. My issue is that this is a very useful question (at least to me as I couldn't find another closely related question) but may eventually get closed and disappear.

Fortunately, the OP is a fairly frequent user so may try to include some basic code to keep the question open (I added a [comment to request this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/selecting-features-within-certain-buffer-distance-of-selected-feature-using-pyqg#comment395684_223497)).

But if no code is provided, should this question (and others like it) be placed on-hold and risk losing valuable answers?

Comment: Close reasons are there to help reviewers providing accurate feedback to OPs. However, their fitness to questions can vary according to each reviewer's interpretation. It can happen sometimes a question does not have code, but it illustrates what is wanted to the point satisfactory answers are possible. In such cases, users with >3k rep can vote to reopen and explain the reason why. I voted for reopening (it will be sent to the reopen queue), you can add up your reopen vote, if you want to. Five reopen votes will reopen the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why this question and its answers would "eventually get closed and disappear" unless the question and both its answers start to receive sufficient downvotes to take away their positive voting record.  To assist their survival (which I think is in no doubt anyway) I upvoted both answers.  If there had been a reasonable code attempt in the question I would have upvoted (rather than voted to close) that too.

The only thing that closing this question does is indicate that it does not meet the current criteria for question quality, and therefore no new answers can be added.

There is no need for the asker to add code to their question now that it has been answered.  The closing is to prevent future users pointing at it and saying "but that user didn't provide code and still got great answers".

For more information about what voting to place On Hold (and eventually Closed) means see:

[What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question)

The criteria for questions to be deleted are described at:

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: Ah ok, I always thought questions which were "put on-hold" would eventually get "closed" and then "deleted". Thanks for the link, I just read that before you edited it in ;)